# Transform stereographic projection using GDAL

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

How can I read/wrap a JPG image without any embedded projection/coordinate system to an autoreferenced GEOTIFF with Mercator or similar coordinate system using GDAL?

The image is 500x500 px and I know it uses a polar stereographic projection with center at 40ºN,3ºW and that it's spation resolution is 3.2Km x 3.2Km.
[image: Image to read/convert]

I suppose I've to go with gdalwrap with +proj=stere but it's not clear to me how to specify the other parameters.

Comment: 40 goes on +lat_0, -3 goes on +lon_0 but what is +lat_ts (latitude of true scale)? and possibly other details, false e/n, what datum, variants of stereographic - this string or better an auth:code or wkt is the -a_srs arg of gdal_translate - also need extent in -ullr in projected coords, then can gdalwarp that

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same thing ages ago with the same image ;-) The easiest thing was to collect a bunch of ground control points (GCPs) where you know e.g. the lat/lon and pixel location, and use them to georreference the image. Basically, if you store your pixel coordinates and (say) lat/long on a DataFrame.

One thing to remember is that you can quickly convert your image to GeoTIFF first so that you can just update the GCPs (I don't think you can do it on PNGs).

```py
from osgeo import gdal, osr
fname = "radar_aemet.tif"
ds = gdal.Open(fname, gdal.GA_Update)
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(4326) # Assume you're using WGS84 

# dataframe. Basically:
# 1. Map coordinates easting
# 2. Map coordinates northing
# 3. Map elevation
# 4. Column (in image)
# 5. Row (in image)

gcps = [gdal.GCP(row.x_map, row.y_map, row.z, row.i_pix, row.j_pix),
            for j, row in df.iterrows()]
# Set the GCP in the dataset
ds.SetGCPs(gcps, sr.ExportToWkt())

# Close file
ds = None
```

At that point, you can wrap (`gdal.Warp`) the image to whatever coordinate system you want, as the file is now georeferenced.

Alternatively, you can use the QGIS georeference plugin to get the GCPs and create a GDAL script to apply to a bunch of images.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the reference coordinate system with defined corner latitude and longitude using gdalwrap.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: no you can't ..